# Stuck in 'Cavern Entrance' level

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I'm having trouble getting through an on-rails (mostly) section of Tomb Raider ('Cavern Entrance' level), and need to know where to point the camera for the next jump (presumably).  Below is the video I recorded from the last checkpoint to where I die:

To be a little more clear, I'm at the point where

> I have to cross a bridge in order to rescue Sam (and maybe others).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as you land on your problematic building, you should notice a climbable wall.

In the video, immediately upon landing on the building, it is straight ahead on the left edge of the screen. Simply jump to that, hit it with your climbing axe, and you should have no trouble proceeding from there.

[image]